# How to append data from an array to mutable array without overwriting the current data in mutable array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Everytime i copy data from array to mutable array, the previous content in the mutable array is lost.

This is my code.

```
for (i=0;i<k;i++)
     {
        o=[[marray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"district_id"];


         j= [o isEqualToString:oo];

         if (j==1)
         {


             dummymarray = [marray objectAtIndex:i];

         }
       }
```

Comment: try to add object from existing array so you can not loss previous data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the dummyArray is the Mutable Array, you like to append the values coming from the working array:marry.

```
[dummyArray addObject:[marray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

addObject to dummyarray:

```
NSObject *object=[[NSObject alloc]init]; 

for (i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    o=[[marray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"district_id"];
    j=[o isEqualToString:oo];

    if (j==1)
    {
        object=[marray objectAtIndex:i];
        [dummymarray addObject:object];
    }
}
```